# Is it possible to convert nested Kotlin classes to a collection containing subcollections in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a simple way to convert something like this

```
data class Pet (
    val owner: Owner = Owner()
)

data class Owner (
    val name: String? = null,
    val email: String? = null
)
```

to a Firestore collection automatically?

This doesn't work for me:

```
val owner = Owner("Joe", "test@test.com")
val pet = Pet("Petty", owner)

db.collection("pets").add(pet)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.  When you `add()` an object, it is converted to a single document.  If you need to create multiple documents, then you will also need multiple calls to `add()` or `set()`, each with the data to put in the document.